# Directory Groups: Reseller account always gets groups for reseller rather than customer

Tags: google-admin-sdk

According to the [Directory API Prerequisites](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites), resellers should be able to perform API calls against their customer's Google Apps instance (except for mobile and chrome device calls). This is done by [specifying the customer's `customerId` attribute](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_all_users) rather than that of the reseller (or the generic `my_customer`).

I am finding though that when performing [groups API calls](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/list), even when specifying the customer's `customerId`, I get back results for the reseller domain, not the customer. It seems `customerId` is entirely ignored for groups.list() operations. If I specify the `domain` attribute and not `customerId`, I do get back the groups for that customer domain but this is not helpful for a multi-domain customer where I may not know all of the customer's domains (and have no way to discover them all).

Is anyone else experiencing this issue or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hey Jay, we can reproduce this issue and have triaged the bug on our end.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google support has resolved this issue on the backend. This now works with no changes to my code.